# CI PHPExcel, How to import one multi-sheet xlsx to multiple table in sql database?

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

As I state in the title,

Is it possible to do such thing?

May I have the example?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this is jquery it will be easy to do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <table id="tbl1" class="table2excel">
            <tr>
                <td>Product</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Available</td>
                <td>Count</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bred</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                 <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Butter</td>
                <td>4   </td>
                <td>5   </td>
                <td>6  </td>
            </tr>
      </table>
    <hr>
    <table id="tbl2" class="table2excel">
            <tr>
                <td>Product</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Available</td>
                <td>Count</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bred</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Butter</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td >16</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <hr>
    <table id="tbl3" class="table2excel">
            <tr>
                <td>Product</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Available</td>
                <td>Count</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bred</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Butter</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td >16</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr>
    <table id="tbl4" class="table2excel">
            <tr>
                <td>Product</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Available</td>
                <td>Count</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bred</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Awss</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td >16</td>
            </tr>
        </table>


    <button  onclick="tablesToExcel(['tbl1','tbl2','tbl3','tbl4'], ['ProductDay1','ProductDay2','Sheet3','Sheet4'], 'TestBook.xls', 'Excel')">Export to Excel</button>


    <script>
     var tablesToExcel = (function() {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">'
          + '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>Axel Richter</Author><Created>{created}</Created></DocumentProperties>'
          + '<Styles>'
          + '<Style ss:ID="Currency"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Currency"></NumberFormat></Style>'
          + '<Style ss:ID="Date"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Medium Date"></NumberFormat></Style>'
          + '</Styles>' 
          + '{worksheets}</Workbook>'
        , tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}"><Table>{rows}</Table></Worksheet>'
        , tmplCellXML = '<Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}><Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</Data></Cell>'
        , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function(tables, wsnames, wbname, appname) {
          var ctx = "";
          var workbookXML = "";
          var worksheetsXML = "";
          var rowsXML = "";

          for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
            if (!tables[i].nodeType) tables[i] = document.getElementById(tables[i]);
            for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
              rowsXML += '<Row>'
              for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
                var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
                var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
                var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
                dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue:tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
                var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
                dataFormula = (dataFormula)?dataFormula:(appname=='Calc' && dataType=='DateTime')?dataValue:null;
                ctx = {  attributeStyleID: (dataStyle=='Currency' || dataStyle=='Date')?' ss:StyleID="'+dataStyle+'"':''
                       , nameType: (dataType=='Number' || dataType=='DateTime' || dataType=='Boolean' || dataType=='Error')?dataType:'String'
                       , data: (dataFormula)?'':dataValue
                       , attributeFormula: (dataFormula)?' ss:Formula="'+dataFormula+'"':''
                      };
                rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
              }
              rowsXML += '</Row>'
            }
            ctx = {rows: rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i};
            worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
            rowsXML = "";
          }

          ctx = {created: (new Date()).getTime(), worksheets: worksheetsXML};
          workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);



          var link = document.createElement("A");
          link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
          link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
          link.target = '_blank';
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
          document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
      })();

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. put all **PHPExcel-1.8** code in third_party/PHPExcel-1.8
2. Create **libraries/Excel.php** as below. this is wrapper on PHPExcel lib.

require_once APPPATH . "/third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php";

```
class Excel extends PHPExcel {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    private function parseFile($filePath){
             //Create excel reader after determining the file type
        $inputFileName = $filePath;
        /**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  * */
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        /**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  * */
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        /** Set read type to read cell data onl * */
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        /**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  * */
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
            //Get worksheet and built array with first row as header
        $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getAllSheets();
            //excel with first row header, use header as key
        $worksheet = array();
        foreach ($objWorksheet as $key => $PHPExcel_Worksheet){
                //excel sheet with no header
            $worksheet[$key] = $PHPExcel_Worksheet->toArray(null, true, true, false);

        }
        return $worksheet;
    }
}
```

*Now You can use this Custom lib in your controller or model using CI's loader.*

3. For example your controller having method like below.

   function do_upload() {

   ```
   $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
   $config['allowed_types'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel|application/x-csv|text/x-csv|text/csv|application/csv|application/excel|application/vnd.msexcel|application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet|application/zip|application/vnd.ms-excel|application/excel|xls|xlsx|csv';
   $config['max_size'] = '10240'; // in KB
   $this->load->library('upload', $config);
   $this->upload->do_upload();
   $this->load->library('Excel');
   $DatainArray = $this->excel->parseFile($this->upload->upload_path . $this->upload->file_name);
   ```

   //do some For loop and insert data to your database.enter code here
   var_dumpt($DatainArray);
    }

Comment: i am here assume that you know how to Insert Query work in CI